# Winform transparent LinkLabel

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make my link label which is placed over a picture box to be transparent. Several things I have tried so far like.

Setting the linklabel's parent to picturecontrol and making the backcolor transparent

```
  this.linkLabel1.Parent = pictureBox1;
  this.linkLabel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

Creating a subclass for my control and played with the ExStyle

```
public class TransparentLinkLabel : LinkLabel
{
  public TransparentLinkLabel()
  {
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
  }
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
    get
    {
      CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
      parms.ExStyle |= 0x20;  // Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
      return parms;
    }
  }
}
```

So far no luck. Any further clues?

Comment: look at my answer, I think it will solve your problem you just need to set the point text should be written and of course font and font color as you wish

Comment: Both a Label or a LinkLabe __will__ be transparent with just the two first lines in your question. No need to subclass, let alone drawstring anything! __Don't forget to set the linklabel.Location!!__ Here is a small detail about PictureBox: When you put a control on it, it will __not__ be added to its controls collection; so the initial loccation will be wrong. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066477/recover-previous-absolute-position-for-picturebox-when-parent-is-changed/30071783#30071783) for a handy function to let you design in the designer and make things work in code!!

Comment: Changing the Parent works just fine, you'll need to do a better job demonstrating your problem.  Make a small repro project if necessary.

Comment: Solved with the location trick along with parent set to picturebox.